# Form submit catched by ajax and result an infinity loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a question in ajax and html forms, And i need your helps please.

I'm using PARSLEY validation (http://parsleyjs.org/) for validation rules. But the probleme is that validation doesn't support the database validations : for instant, i have to check if the field 'nom' already exist in database or no, if exist (show a message) and if don't exist submit the form to myaction.php.

My ajax script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit
        var nom = $("#nom").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data:  "field="+ nom ,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data==1){
                    alert(data);
                }else if(data==0){
                    cache: false
                    $('form#form_id').submit();
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

My html form :

```
<form action="myaction.php" method="post" name="form_name" id="form_id">
    <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" required value="">
    <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" required value="">
    <input type="text" id="remarque" name="remarque" required value="">
</form>
```

ajax.php : return 0 if field doesn't exist in database and 1 if exist

The probleme i face is that the ajax called in a loop. in each time the form submited and call the ajax. what i want is if data equal 0 (field doesn't exist in database) the form must be submited to myaction.php

Comment: are you saying it's not recognising the data returned? try checking the returned data as a string: `data=='1'` etc

Comment: Don't work.. The same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution.

Basically you're submitting and handling the submision forever. You need to break that when the data has been validated. Since you only care about `nom`, set some flag on it so you can check whenever you're submitting

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        var nom = $('#nom');
        var valid = nom.data('valid');

        if (valid === 0) { // Is valid, let's continue
          return;
        } else { // Valid is undefined as was never set
          e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'ajax.php',
              data:  "field="+ nom.val() ,
              success: function (data) {                
                  if(data==1) {
                      alert(data);
                  } else if(data==0) {
                    nom.data('valid', 0);
                  }
              }
          });
        }                
    });
});
```

Comment: Tested, It's exactly what i want, But the probleme here is that when data == 0 the form must be submited automaticly, I use this $('form#form_id').submit(); after nom.data('valid', 0); but it does't work

Comment: I found why, the submit input cannot have the name submit. Thank you for help